# Display the value of multiple checkboxes in another page after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display the value of multiple checkbox in another page using local storage on form submit.

This is the 1st page where I'm having my checkbox.

```
<p id="qualifications">Qualifications:</p>
<label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="BE" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="MCA" id="checkbox2">
```

This is the second page where I want to show the the values such as MCA or BE on form submit. It was easy to show in the popup window but not in other page.

```
<p> Qualification: <span id="display_qualifications"></span> </p>
```

This is the script I'm using and it's showing null in 2nd page.

```
 // qualification storing value of checkbox now need to store inside localstorage

var qualification = $("#checkbox1").val();
var qualification1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
localStorage.setItem('qualification1', qualification1);
localStorage.setItem('qualification', qualification);

var qualification = localStorage.getItem("qualification");
var qualification1 = localStorage.getItem("qualification1");
$("#display_qualifications").text(qualification);
$("#display_qualifications").text(qualification1);
```

Comment: Did you checked the console log ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its showing null because you are not setting values of checkboxes in first page.

```
<p id="qualifications">Qualifications:</p>
<label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="BE" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="MCA" id="checkbox2">
```

Assign value MCA and BE to checkboxes.

### Update

Got the error. You have misspelled "Qualification".

```
var qualifiaction = $("#checkbox1").val();
var qualifiaction1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
localStorage.setItem('qualification1', qualification1);
localStorage.setItem('qualification', qualification);
```

qualifiaction != qualification And qualifiaction1 != qualification1

So change the var name like this.

```
var qualification = $("#checkbox1").val();
var qualification1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
localStorage.setItem('qualification1', qualification1);
localStorage.setItem('qualification', qualification);
```

Also check all the spellings in your code.

### Update 2

Working Demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xq8vcomw/3/)

Comment: I did it.. I forgot to write here.. Still same result.

Comment: Check the update in my answer. @Nitin **TIP**: Never write the names when you can copy them. :)

Comment: I did what you said and now to get im doing: var qualification = localStorage.getItem("qualification");
     var qualification1 = localStorage.getItem("qualification1");                      $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification);
 But still not showing.

Comment: Check my update 2 in answer. I have created a jsfiddle. Use that code and it will work. @Nitin

Comment: yes in your example its showing . But ur trying to show the result in same page i guess. But im trying it in different page i think something converting it to string is required. Because its showing Null, Null.

Comment: You can check if the localStorage value is set or not in your browser press F12 and in developer window go to storage tab. Go to local storage and see if values are getting stored? @Nitin

Comment: hey its showing but bot the values are showing if i do  $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification+ " " +qualification1);     and only the one value show if i do $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification);         $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification1);

Comment: In your demo try to select 1 checkbox and then display the output. Both the options will display.

Comment: Yes because thats not you have asked for... @Nitin read your question again. NVM I am updating my demo.

Answer (score 1):

Here you replacing the value and missing value attribute -

```
$("#display_qualifications").text(qualification);
$("#display_qualifications").text(qualification1);
```

You can see display_qualifications area can't show both value so you need to concat both value like -

```
var concatString = qualification + "" + qualification1;
console.log(concatString)
```

Comment: This is because your sapling mistake on variable and saving value are different var qualifiaction = $("#checkbox1").val();
var qualifiaction1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
localStorage.setItem('qualification1', qualification1);
localStorage.setItem('qualification', qualification);

Comment: qualifiaction using getting for value but you storing qualification both are different just because of sapling mistake.

Comment: i understand what you are saying. I have corrected the spelling:           
      var qualification = $("#checkbox1").val();
       var qualification1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
       var concatString = (qualification +" "+ qualification1) ;                          
       localStorage.setItem('concatString', concatString);                            
      var concatString = localStorage.getItem("concatString");                        
      $("#display_qualifications").html(concatString);        Tell me what mistake im doing here

Comment: Here you need use append instead of html because html just replacing your previous value.

Comment: No append is not working. Im getting the values but  both the values are showing if i do $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification+ " " +qualification1); and only  one value show if i do $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification); $("#display_qualifications").html(qualification1);

Comment: witch value you can see on console

Comment: both values are visible

Comment: what is your desire output?

Comment: I want to display only the checked field.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Set values**

```
<p id="qualifications">Qualifications:</p>
<label for="checkbox1">BE</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="BE" id="checkbox1">
<label for="checkbox2">MCA</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="MCA" id="checkbox2">
```

**2. Append result and not overwrite**

```
$("#display_qualifications").text(qualification + qualification1);
```

Comment: Log the value of qualification and qualification1 before storing them and see what's that value.

Comment: var qualifiaction = $("#checkbox1").val();
     var qualifiaction1 = $("#checkbox2").val();
         
  var concatString = qualification + "" + qualification1;
     console.log(concatString);          this is what im doing and error showing qualification not defined.

Comment: its showing the value in console. Then              localStorage.setItem('education', concatString);                                     var concatString = localStorage.getItem("education");                                       $("#display_qualifications").html(concatString);             Is showing no result

Comment: Tell me if im doing it correct now :      var qualification = $("#checkbox1").val(); var qualification1 = $("#checkbox2").val(); var concatString = (qualification +" "+ qualification1) ; localStorage.setItem('concatString', concatString); var concatString = localStorage.getItem("concatString"); $("#display_qualifications").html(concatString);    Its still showing nothing